# Is there anyway to capture hardware accelerated views without using media projection API?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaprojection

I am trying to get screenshot of an activity that contains hardware accelerated view's so , Is there a way to get a activity screenshot without using [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection) API or getting the hardware accelerated view's bitmap only ?

Comment: Well, could you add more description, are you trying to find another way to capture screen?

Comment: @Ibrahim updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PixelCopy API
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy

```
public static void request (SurfaceView source, 
            Bitmap dest, 
            PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener listener, 
            Handler listenerThread)
```